# Error 500 or Rewrite Rule to get clean URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error when using the following Rewrite rule in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Essentially, I want clean urls on my web application, i.e. *www.example.com/login* would function the same as *www.example.com/index.php/login*.

This rewrite rule works fine locally on MAMP and on a different Apache test server, but fails on the client's 1and1.com-based hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php).*$ index.php/$0 [L,QSA]
```

You need to prevent the infinite loop.  A negative assertion on `index.php` is one way to stop this.

Comment: Not sure if I like negative assertions, but it saves a RewriteCond. I should look into those. +1 for making me aware of their existence :-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer over at the [CodeIgniter forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/98536/).

It didn't fix my rule, but instead went at it a slightly different way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1 [L]
```